# Cant get JSON POST data using Slim v3

Tags: php, json, slim

Im using Slim v3 . Installed via composer. 
Here is my register.php file :

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]);


//-------------- Register ------------------ 
$app->post('/', function (Request $request, Response $response   ,$args)    use($app) {

$json =$request->getParams();
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$response->getBody()->write($data);

return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

When i post sample Json like`{"name":"jack", "age":"10", "gender":"male"}`
via postman i get RuntimeException error `Could not write to stream` .
I already use `$app->request()->post();` and `$request->getParams();` and `$request->getParsedBody();` but i face other errors like undefined method and so on .
Please Help me.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
//-------------- Register ------------------ 
$app->post('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) use ($app) {
    $json =$request->getParams();
    return $response->withJson($json);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to use `getBody()` with the request, not `getParams`:

```
$json =$request->getBody();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. problem still exists. i think its because of $args .
do i really need that ? or use($app) @iturki

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar I don't think so. Are you using Slim 3 or 2?

Comment: Version 3.  i Figure it out ! the problem was $args .